# What are the best free tools to make wireframes of a website?

Tags: web-development, wireframing, freetype

Well I have used pencil but its basically for making mockups for mobile applications. Could you please suggest free tools/websites to make wireframe for websites ?

Comment: Good question but could you give us some more details like what os you want it to run on or some specific features that you want